# Java Intellij warning: condition always true when reached

Tags: java, intellij-idea

With following code:

```
public class Container {

    private final List<Thing> things;

    public Container() {
        this.things = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean addThing(Thing thing) {
        return thing != null && things.add(thing);
    }
    ...
}
```

IntelliJ gives me:

> Condition 'things.add(thing)' is always 'true' when reached

When thing is null only the first condition is played and false is returned
I think this line is well optimized easy to read but maybe I miss something...
Is it a false warning ?
Is there a way to remove this warning ?

Comment: `this.things` can *never* be null when you call `addThing` - you have a constructor that initializes `this.things`, and `things` is also declared to be final (i.e. cannot be changed after initialization). The warning is correct.

Comment: @nbokmans the null check is for `thing`, not `things` (admittedly unclear naming). The reason that `things#add` is always `true` is because `List#add` is always `true` to begin with, per the [javadoc for List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-). A clearer way to write this may be `if (thing == null) return false; ... things.add(thing);`, as it makes it more readable/clear imo

Comment: Yes @Rogue it's about `thing`, your solution works, no more warning, it takes longer to write but it's more readable, yes in this case it is surely a warning about readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I find your code fine.
However the `Arraylist#add(Object)` implementation always returns true.
And that delivered the code style warning.

```
public boolean addThing(Thing thing) {
    if (thing == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return things.add(thing);
}
```

I would write the above: saying you do not add nulls.

Comment: Yes, same solution as @Rogue, it takes longer to write but it's certainly more readable. Thanks